# ThreadPoolExecutor consuming from multiple PriorityBlockingQueues

Tags: concurrency, java-8, priority-queue

I have the task of scheduling & executing a lot of web-request, in java 8, with the following conditions:

1. each web-request belongs to exactly one of distinct groups

   - the group a web-request belongs to is an immutable and deterministic property of the request (i.e. is not a result of some (pseudo-)random logic), e.g. imagine the user on behalf the request is being made
2. the web-service is tracking the quota usage of web-requests it receives, for each of these distinct group
3. a web-request may receive an HTTP 429 (Too Many Requests) at any given moment, indicating that the quota for that group is full

   - when this happens, no more web-requests of the same group are allowed to be made until the stated time indicated by the Retry-After header of the response, such futile requests still count as part of the quota
   - web-requests of a non-throttled group can, and should be processed regardless of some other groups being throttled
4. some requests are more equal then others, therefore eligible requests should be processed in some priority order
5. the number of these distinct quota groups is in the few hundreds (for now)
   at any given moment a new group may be born, e.g. a new user joins the organization

I've been collecting some ideas, none of which I am satisfied with:

- The most obvious is that each group could be handled by their very own ThreadPoolExecutor consuming from a respective PriorityBlockingQueue

  - Simplicity has its virtues, but I kind of dislike running hundred instances of ThreadPoolExecutors (even if each and every one of them is using a single thread for execution).
- I could (try to) go down the tedious and quite error-prone path of implementing my own BlockingQueue, with a PriorityQueue maintained for each group

  - the number of interface methods in BlockingQueue is not that many, but the designers of that concurrency library saw fit to extend Collection and Queue interfaces, and just the amount of time to implement all *those* methods and test them too sounds like a (dangerous) waste of time to me
- I could also go and relax the goal of letting non-throttled groups&requests to progress, and just block all requests until stated time

  - this may not be as bad as it sounds, I will still have to check how easy it is to hit the quota limit and what the time penalty is - 5 minutes blackout ever other week sounds almost acceptable, half an hour every midnight is definitely not OK
- Another idea is to have ThreadPoolExecutor with a single PriorityBlockingQueue (PBQ) with a map of throttled group -> request-lists on the side

  - on several occasions (on submit, on consuming from main PBQ, and even on just having received an HTTP 429 response), the group of the request would be tested for being throttled, and if it's that the case, the request would be put to that throttled group -> request list map
  - but normally, requests would just be consumed by the ThreadPoolExecutor
  - of course, whenever some throttling period indicated by Retry-After header of the HTTP 429 response has ended, the respective group would wake up and all it's requests would be re-submitted to the main PBQ
- I've also been reading up on RxJava, but none of the delay, throttle or backpressure facilities are suitable - or at least I coulnd't see how.

At this point I really don't expect any pseudo-code (well, unless it's actually shorter that way), but I am most interested in better ideas or perhaps pointers to existing facilities.

(Btw, the web-service is the Microsoft Graph API, in case anyone wonders.)

Comment: What kind of requests are you making to Microsoft Graph?  If you can explain, I might be able to provide tips on how to optimize. For example, batching, delta query, etc.

Comment: Ideally, we want to query calendar events like $filter=(isOrganizer+eq+true)+and+(location/displayName+eq+'Room1'+or+location/displayName+eq+'Room2') would reduce the request count, but it gets us ErrorInternalServerError, even though either of the sub-clauses work alone. Most other expressions are either not supported or trigger error (e.g. the 'any' lambda operators). Anyway, we have some ideas how to reduce the number of queries: e.g. fetch organizer events, filter the result by rooms of interest on our side, track changes based on iCalUid+changeKey. But, throttling still needs attention.